# compare between two times ubuntu shell script

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell-scripting

I am working on a shell script which will do some things if the current time is between 19:00 and 1:00 am, so I  get the current time in this way:

```
 currenttime=$(date +%H%M%S);
```

and I convert the starttime and endtime format like this:

```
 starttime=$(date -d 19:00 '+%H%M%S');

 endtime=$(date -d 01:00 '+%H%M%S');
```

so I make this condition to check if the current time is between 19 and 1 AM:

```
num1=$(($starttime-$currenttime))
num2=$(($endtime-$currenttime))


if [ $num1 -lt 0 -a $num2 -gt 0 ];
 then
 echo "the current time is between 19:00 and 01:00 "
 else 
 echo "the current time is not in range  "
  fi
```

so if current time is:

> 20:00

the value of `num1` will be:

> 190000 - 20000= -1000

and the value of `num2` will be:

> 010000 - 20000=  -10000

so the condition will not apply  because `num2` always smaller than zero.  Please help. How can I make true comparison?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you may be taking on too much at once by trying to combine both cases into a single test.

You may find it helpful to approach this problem by splitting the test into two cases:

1. Is the time between 1900 and midnight?
2. Is the time between midnight and 0100?

And finally, your usage of **between** is somewhat ambiguous.  What if the time is exactly 19:00 or exactly 01:00?  Is that "between" the limits or not?  Using different values as an example, a strict interpretation of "between" might dictate that the only integer "between" 1 and 3 is 2.  These are sometimes called "edge cases" and your problem as stated does not fully define what result you want when one of these edge cases arises.